# Plotting two separate NDSolve solutions together

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
gsln = NDSolve[{eqnx1[t], eqny1[t], eqnz1[t], eqnx2[t], eqny2[t], 
eqnz2[t], x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10,.....
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{(y1sln[t]/rc), (z1sln[t]/rc)}], {t, 0, end}]
```

Generally I am able to plot the `y1` solution with the `z1` solution. I would also like to overlap that plot with the `y2` solution as well as the `z2` solution. How would I go about writing the code to do so?

*`rc` is used to normalize.*

Comment: Can you maybe give an actual example that other people can evaluate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To combine two graphics in one frame, we need to use `Show`. Here I consider two random systems of differential equations, because you haven't provided any.

```
sol1[x0_?NumericQ] := 
  First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.2*(x[t] - x[t]*y[t]), 
     y'[t] == Sin[t - 4]*(x[t]*y[t] - y[t]), x[0] == x0, 
     y[0] == x0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];

sol2[U0_?NumericQ] := 
  First@NDSolve[{U'[t] == 0.1*(U[t] - U[t]*V[t]), 
     V'[t] == Sin[t - 3]*(U[t]*V[t] - V[t]), U[0] == U0, 
     V[0] == U0}, {U, V}, {t, 0, 20}];

p1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol1[#] & /@ Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t, 0,
     20}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.3}, {0, 2.6}}, Frame -> True];

p2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{U[t], V[t]} /. sol2[#] & /@ Range[0.9, 1.8, 0.1]], {t, 0,
     20}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.3}, {0, 2.6}}, Frame -> True];

Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly it, thank you!